# Why does a Worklight Hybrid application quits/crashes immediately on Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, ibm-mobilefirst

App created in worklight immediately closes after its been deployed on android emulator. Even the simple HelloWorklight app quits immediately.

Comment: More information would help. Which version of worklight? Which version of the emulator? Would you happen to know the architecture of the emulator (x86/ armv7)? Any messages shown in logcat?

Comment: Check your logcat window for clues on what could be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible culprits:

1. You are using an AVD running Android OS v2.3.x - Google has a bug there, causes apps to crash. Use either Android OS v2.2.x or 3.x or 4.x.
2. You are using Worklight v5.0.5 and have only Android API Level 17 installed - upgrade to Worklight v5.0.6.x, where this defect has been resolved.

As mentioned in the comments section of your question, if the above suggestions fail to resolve your issue, add to your question what you get in LogCat upon application launch.